# mysqli bind_param (si) wont work

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert a value to my database using mysqli bind_param.

My code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."u_nm  (uname,umobile) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $this->name, $this->mobile);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
?>
```

- **uname** is the users name, so it should be a string `bind_param("s")`
- **umobile** is the users mobile number so it should be `bind_param("i")`

*But the whole number wont insert if I put umobile as `("i")`?*

**Example:**

Lets say I insert the name Billy and the number 0739871169

Then inside the DB it would show up as:

```
Billy
739871169
```

instead of

```
Billy
0739871169
```

But if I change bind_param to `("ss")` instead of `("si")` it works fine,

But shouldn't a number be marked as `("i")` or am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It accepts the number as an integer (ie. no leading zeros). You may add the "zerofill" option in the mobile phone field, or just accept it as a string.